# Regex to capture exact numbers in string

Tags: python, regex

I have a column that looks like this:

```
11/33/4500030050
4100000300/4503134501
4100030300+4503114501
11
```

The regular expression should capture the following:

```
4500030050
4100000300/4503134501
4100030300+4503114501
''
```

Here's my current regular expression:

```
 col.str.findall(r'[/+ #_;.-]?(?<![0-9])[0-9]{10}(?![0-9])').str.join('').str.lstrip('/+ #_;.-')
```

This however captures all numbers that have 10 digits. How can I modify so that it can only capture numbers that start with 41 and 45?

Comment: `4[15][0-9]{8}` - start with 4, then 1 or 5 followed by 8 digits instead of `[0-9]{10}`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I tried this: `[+ #_;.-]?4[15][0-9]{8}(?![0-9])` but not getting the result

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Sorry, I think this maybe correct. RIght?

Comment: `4[15][0-9]{8}([+ #_;.\/-]4[15][0-9]{8})?` https://regex101.com/r/4rZpDv/1

Comment: You need `[+ #_;.-]?(?<![0-9])4[15][0-9]{8}(?![0-9])`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/e4GBtA/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[+ #_;.-]?(?<![0-9])4[15][0-9]{8}(?![0-9])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e4GBtA/1).

*Details*:

- `[+ #_;.-]?` - an optional `+`, space, `#`, `_`, `;`, `.` or `-`
- `(?<![0-9])` - left digit boundary
- `4` - a `4` digit char
- `[15]` - `1` or `5`
- `[0-9]{8}` - eight digits
- `(?![0-9])` - right digit boundary.